# Authentication issue with spring security, JWT on resource API

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, angular5, jhipster

I am having a issue related to authentication where I am getting logged out of my app when trying to GET from an endpoint that was created from a POST (HTTTP STATUS 201) I see the following errors. The backend is seeing the user as anonymousUser while I am logged in but works fine for another endpoint in the same file :

> 2018-10-22 11:33:35.251 DEBUG 2124 --- [ XNIO-8 task-23]
>   c.c.link.aop.logging.LoggingAspect   : Enter:
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with
>   argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Oct 22 11:33:35 PDT 2018,
>   principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE,
>   data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffed504:
>   RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId:
>   _5aP-S8x27gGSIjtbkR6EwrWOD9Yybnd-4M3z0ol, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException,
>   message=Access is denied}]] 2018-10-22 11:33:35.258 DEBUG 2124 --- [
>   XNIO-8 task-23] c.c.link.aop.logging.LoggingAspect   : Exit:
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with
>   result = null 2018-10-22 11:33:35.343  WARN 2124 --- [ XNIO-8 task-23]
>   o.z.p.spring.web.advice.AdviceTrait      : Unauthorized: Full
>   authentication is required to access this resource

The same resource (DeliveryResource.java) has an endpoint that works fine
the only difference between both end points is one is /getList (this one is working fine) VS. /getPackingListReport/{number} (this one fails authentication).

The API definitions are shown below:

```
@GetMapping("/getPackingListReport/{number}")
@Secured(AuthoritiesConstants.USER)
@Timed
public ArrayList<WebOrder> getPackingListReportFromDB(@PathVariable("number") long packingListNbr)
```

vs.

```
@GetMapping("/getList")
@Secured(AuthoritiesConstants.USER)
@Timed
public WebOrder getList(@RequestParam(value = "custid") long custid,@RequestParam(value = "pId") long pId) {
```

Comment: Check how you configured `HttpSecurity`.

Comment: The URL for that resource is configured under HttpSecurity as .antMatchers("/delivery/**").authenticated()

So the full URL would be /delivery/getPackingListReport/{number}.

/delivery/getList works fine while 

/delivery/getPackingListReport/{number} does not.

Comment: Your URLs are not very RESTful, resources should be nouns not verbs.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I was using the following for the "/getList" mapping:

```
    // call dao to insert to DB the list and then call the stored proc
    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/api/rest/getPackingListReport/{packingListNumber}").buildAndExpand(packingListNumber).toUri();

    return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
```

to return a created resource URI (HTTP STATUS 201) after a POST. That path contained the incorrect URI starting with , "http://localhost" when jHipster is currently default set to only handle and look for "/api" or in my case i added "/rest/api/*" on the Angular5 side.

I fixed the issue by filtering out any characters before "/api/" after receiving the URL.